# Median for every nth values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, median

I don't have much experience with Matlab.
I have a row vector with 17497 elements and I would like to create a loop to get the median of every 120 values.

So, the median of value 1:120, then the next median of values 121:240 and so on.

Could somebody help me?

Thanks in advance,
Sunna

Answer (score 1):

You could use `accumarray`

```
N = 17497;
data = rand(N,1);
%# array with 1,1,1,2,2,2 etc
idx = floor((0:N-1).'/120)+1;
%# create median for groups of 120 data points
%# discard the last one if needed as it's <120 points
out = accumarray(idx,data,[],@median);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you simply ignore the last few elements in your row vector such that the row can be equally divided into parts of 120. You can then transform your row vector into a 120 row matrix. `median` can operate on this matrix directly and return the median of each column.

```
N = 17497;
A = randn(1,N);
newN = N - mod(N,120);
median(reshape(A(1:newN),120,[]));
```

Comment: @S.Kupfer: `rand` is generating random numbers, `rand(2,3)` is creating a random array of size [2,3], for example.

Comment: @Jonas, Thanks! Both of your solutions helped me a lot and worked perfetly well!